# flutter button has spacing at the top

Tags: flutter, button, layout

```
Widget tabTitleDetails = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 8,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      
  
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0) ,
              margin:EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                
                  RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        child:new Text('Sell')
                  ),
                      
                ],
              )
            ),
            numDetails
          ],
        )
    
      );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neGJC.jpg)

problems:
this codes run ,the screen show the button is the distance from the top

Comment: You know you got symetric padding set at the top of 8px

Comment: sorry,i don't konw,Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`, to your `FlatButton`.

This is because Flutter has default button size to 48*48, so if your button size is less then that Flutter will provide padding to it. You can also increase the Height to greater than 48. Here is [Flutter Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2994d3562a0abb4a4db0fefdab27907e934cd161/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L206).

Comment: Thank you very much!!It's quite useful to me.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this solved your problem. Thanks